# What can cause slow planning times for "select 1"?

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-rds

I have a database that is used by a Production application. It's an db.m3.medium on Amazon RDS. We've noticed that a lot of queries are starting to get slow that typically shouldn't be slow (e.g. select row by primary key).

We started to investigate the issue and found that our `select 1` health check against the database is *also* slow. For example, here's some graphs about running `explain (analyze buffers) select 1` every second over a ~20 hour period:

#### Duration (round trip time) (ms)

[image: select 1 duration]

I've capped the y-axis at 500 ms.

#### Planning (ms)

[image: select 1 planning]

I've capped the y-axis at 100 ms.

#### Execution (ms)

[image: select 1 execution]

I've capped the y-axis at 100 ms.

---

It seems crazy that *planning* a query is taking such extreme times.

When we look at the database as a whole, there doesn't seem to be any signs that it's under heavy enough load. Here's a typical day:

#### CPU

[image: cpu]

#### Read (blue) / write (purple) throughput (MiB/s)

[image: read/write throughput]

#### Network transmit (purple) / receive (blue) throughput (KiB/s)

[image: network transmit/receive throughput]

#### Disk

The disk is 30 GiB and has 5.75 GiB used.

#### Memory

There is 3.75 GiB of RAM and 2.2 GiB is free.

---

The database instance is new as of December 17, 2017 (after a manual failover from another instance because of required AWS maintenance). Our hypothesis is that the single-core is causing the OS (and Postgres) to have issues context switching. However, none of the metrics of the database really point to the fact that it's running very hot. I can also confirm that we don't have any long-running queries/transactions.

What could be causing simple queries such as `select 1` to have high planning and execution times?

Comment: Is your planning time you use the time reported by the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) itself, or is it arrived at by measuring the round trip time of an EXPLAIN without ANALYZE?

Comment: Install sysstat to monitor your system at the same time as monitoring your database. Aren't there any better tools out there for monitoring the database than `SELECT 1`?Try [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring.html). [PgHero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero) is another tool. The mainstream tools have plugins for PostgreSQL - [Nagios](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/PostgresQL) for example. You can check your CPU - more /proc/cpuinfo - an use sar (sysstat activity report AFAIK) with sysstat.

Comment: @jjanes the planning time is from the output of the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE). The "duration" is the full round trip time of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE).

Comment: @Vérace I'm using Datadog to monitor the RDS instance and am willing to provide other metrics. Otherwise, I can't install anything on the server because it's RDS...

Comment: You might have CPU or disk IO latency spikes that are too transient to show up in the graphs.  Turning on log_planner_stats might help (if RDS will let you do so).  Does the "select 1" open a new connection for each query, or keep a persistent connection?

Comment: Zooming in on the graph doesn't show any disk/CPU spikes either. We're thinking of turning on RDS's [enhanced monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.html) to get a finer grain report of CPU/disk usage. The test that ran "select 1" used the same connection. To clarify, other queries that should be fast are slow too (e.g. loading a row by primary key).

Comment: you're sharing RAM and disk busses with other users. speed will be eratic,

Comment: @Jasen it never used to be like this. Roughly in the past year, things have slowly gotten worse with random queries being extra slow.

Comment: maybe there's more sharing now, how long does postgresql say it's taking to execute `select 1`

Comment: @Jasen ... that's what the first 3 graphs say.

Comment: the only explanation I can think of is that you're running out of ram. that could be caused by disk slowness I guess